# jsfiddle angular not working

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I made a jsfiddle here to make angular question: [https://jsfiddle.net/b6xgjfwg/](https://jsfiddle.net/b6xgjfwg/1)

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    Hello {{name}}
</div>
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Sally';
}
```

same as http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/tcVhN/

But not working.
I am new to jsfiddle and help me.

Comment: it works fine as I see it.

Comment: @JudsonTerrell please see https://jsfiddle.net/b6xgjfwg/1

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b6xgjfwg/5/

Comment: What did you updated?

Comment: see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below screen show. You can see that I specified to load my angular in the head (no-wrap) and also reformatted my code to be more "correct"

[image: changes]

Comment: Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

[try this instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6zb5.png)

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.name = 'Sally';
});
```